# How to Convert Epoch Time in a MySql Join

Tags: mysql, join, epoch

I have a simple mysql query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM User_Info
RIGHT JOIN Log ON User_Info.Key = Log.U_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Log has a epoch time column that needs to be converted. What's the proper syntax for adding a convert during a join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the table as `table.column`.

```
SELECT *, FROM_UNIXTIME(Log.epoch) AS log_time
FROM User_Info
RIGHT JOIN Log ON User_Info.Key = Log.U_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

*Please replace the `epoch` with the correct field name.*

Answer (score 0):

Use the FROM_UNIXTIME function, ie 
    mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1447430881);
        -> '2015-11-13 10:08:01'
    mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1447430881) + 0;
        -> 20151113100801
    mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),
    ->                      '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x');
        -> '2015 13th November 10:08:01 2015'